# Extract records between days

Tags: sql, hive

I have an Audit table for each and every day. All add/modify/delete records are stored. When any record is deleted it doesn’t show up the next day. Something like below.

```
Date    records
----    --------
15th     100    
16th      102      - Pickup all records, between 15 and 16, which are not in 16th
17th     110    - Pickup all records, between 16 and 17, which are not in 17th
18th     150    - Pickup all records, between 17 and 18, which are not in 18th
.. So on..
```

This is an Audit table which has the deleted records in the previous day, but not present today. I need to pick up all the deleted records, between dates.
But I don’t want to hard code the dates, instead, it should work from date to today()

How to achieve this in a single SQL query? I tried using “Union” it works, but with hardcoded dates. Is there any way we can achieve as a generic query which works as of today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation.  The first gets the maximum date for each id.  The second records on the delete on the next day:

```
select max_date + interval 1 day, count(*)
from (select a.id, max(date) as max_date
      from audit a
      group by a.id
     ) t
group by max_date
order by max_date;
```

You might want a `where` clause to limit the maximum date to before the maximum date in the data (otherwise everything will look like it is being deleted on the following day).

An alternative method uses `lead()`:

```
select date + 1, count(*)
from (select a.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date
      from audit a
     ) t
where next_date <> date_add(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) or next_date is null
group by date
order by date;
```

If records can be resurrected and you still want to count them as deleted when they disappear, this is the better method.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=feec82fd56a576421ab155761f73cf64) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I am not sure this is working like the OP wants : see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=12940b87c5c6a5e4de470c16d7b350df

Comment: @Gosfly . . . Thank you very, very much.  On occasion, I don't even know what I was thinking.  The answer was clearly wrong, but it is not fixed.